# How do I determine what's trying to be installed?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, installer

Every morning when I come into work, and log into my Windows XP Pro machine, I get a message box telling me simply, "Wise for Windows Installer".  That's it. Nothing else. No clue as to whatever it is that's trying to install, which never installs.  How do I determine whatever it is that's trying to install itself?

Comment: What kind of message box is it? Can we see a screenshot? Have you looked in your list of processes to see what the process is called?

Comment: If it is a company PC, contact your IT department.